# What causes website render difference?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to prototype project of mine (mobile version of message board). After few hours of html and css I've decided to check how it looks in Chrome  (before it i'm was coding in firefox responsive design mode) and everything was smooth.

I can't figure out which css rules causes it to render this way. And why it looks fine only in FF responsive design mode. Thanks in advance!

[firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2p0l.jpg)

[chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GNeB.jpg)

[prototype link](http://pp.wdgroup.lv/mobile/), so you can inspect css

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: A clearer, more specific problem statement would be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference looks like it is being caused by the lack of a viewport meta tag.

Add this to your head tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This tells the browser to render the page at the width of the device as opposed to trying to render the desktop version of the site and zooming out to fit all the content in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Delete "height: 155px;" into

```
.homepage-gallery__block {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    height: 155px;
    margin: 0 1% 10px;
}
```